# Adding anchor points to powerpoint shapes

Tags: powerpoint

Is there a hands on tutorial for adding anchor-points to powerpoint shapes?
What I have in mind are centers of shapes like circles or the focal points of ellipses; in the latter case the relative coordinates of those additional anchor points would have to be recalculated upon rescaling.

I know workarounds for constucting those points, but its tedious. So may I kindly ask for solutions that give the same look and feel of original anchor points of powerpoint shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Anchor Points are ConnectionSites in ppt-vba if I am not wrong. There is no method for adding them directly. You would have to add nodes (.Nodes.Insert) in your shape first to make them available as anchor points. In order to create anchor points in areas like "focal points of ellipses" you would always need to create shape groups with helper shapes because there is nothing in your shape where your focal point is. 
Have a look at ToolsToo addin which has a tool to add additional anchor points - that's how they approach it.